# How can I provide default expression in the { } of a lambda expression, while still allowing it to be added to?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-ui-grid

I am using the Kendo UI MVC Grid and I want to encapsulate boilerplate code so I don't have to duplicate the same code on every grid. Configuring the commands on the grid looks like this:

```
columns.Command(command =>
            {
                command.Custom("Edit").Text("<span class='k-icon k-edit'></span>").Click("editRecord");
                command.Custom("Delete").Text("<span class='k-icon k-i-delete'></span>").Click("deleteItem");
            }).Width(130);
```

The edit and delete are boilerplate, however there is a potential for extra custom commands depending on the grid. The type of the lambda for command is of `Action<GridActionCommandFactory<T>>`. How can I abstract the boilerplate to a method or something while still allowing custom commands to be entered? Psuedo-coding it out I figure it would look something like this:

```
columns.Command(command =>
            {
                //Custom commands here
                SomeConfigClass.DefaultGridCommands(command);
                //Custom commands here
            }).Width(130);
```

or maybe:

```
columns.Command(command =>
            {
                //Custom commands here
                command.DefaultCommands();
                //Custom commands here
            }).Width(130);
```

And this would include the edit and delete commands. But I have no idea how to modify a lambda expression in such a way, how can I achieve this?

Comment: What's the type of `command` parameter here `columns.Command(command => `? i.e. `Action<GridActionCommandFactory<???>>`

Comment: Doesn't matter, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did some more digging and it ended up not being that hard. Not sure if it's the most elegant solution but I did it like this:

```
public static Action<GridActionCommandFactory<T>> GetDefaultGridCommands<T>(Action<GridActionCommandFactory<T>> customCommandsBeforeDefault = null, Action<GridActionCommandFactory<T>> customCommandsAfterDefault = null) where T : class
    {
        Action<GridActionCommandFactory<T>> defaultCommands = x =>
        {
            x.Custom("Edit").Text("<span class='k-icon k-edit'></span>").Click("editRecord");
            x.Custom("Delete").Text("<span class='k-icon k-i-delete'></span>").Click("deleteItem");
        };

        List<Action<GridActionCommandFactory<T>>> actions = new List<Action<GridActionCommandFactory<T>>>();

        if(customCommandsBeforeDefault != null)
            actions.Add(customCommandsBeforeDefault);
        actions.Add(defaultCommands);
        if(customCommandsAfterDefault != null)
            actions.Add(customCommandsAfterDefault);

        Action<GridActionCommandFactory<T>> combinedAction = (Action<GridActionCommandFactory<T>>) Delegate.Combine(actions.ToArray());

        return combinedAction;
    }
```

Then calling it in the grid:

```
columns.Command(KendoUiGridConfig.GetDefaultGridCommands<MyViewModel>()).Width(130);
```

The `Delegate.Combine` method was what I was looking for.